# Execute code when pointer is released after it was pressed down at selected item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to execute code in JQuery when I let go of the left mouse button after I have pressed it down on `.grid-container`.

I know that there is `mouseup`, but I can't use it because it only works when the pointer is let go off while in the selected item.

```
$('.grid-container').mousedown(function() {
    $('html').addClass('noscroll');
});
$('.grid-container').CLICK_LET_GO_OFF(function() {
    $('html').removeClass('noscroll');
});
```

Comment: I assume you are trying to remove class on (mouse up) or event of letting go of mouse? If so you could just put the mouseup event on the full page?

Comment: Yes, it is removeClass, my fault. Gonna change that.

Comment: Additionally, if I would put it on body, wouldn't it be trigerred even when I don't want it to?

Comment: Yeah, but you would be removing a class that you wouldn't want there anyway. The class wouldn't be there so nothing user facing would happen. You can make it more specific if its only going to happen on a specific page?

Comment: Oh, I see now. It does indeed work, even though it isn't very elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.grid-container').mousedown(function() {
    $('html').addClass('noscroll');
});
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('html').removeClass('noscroll');
});
```

Doing something like this seems to work for me. If you are not wanting them to scroll on clicking within an area and then bringing back the scroll on mouse up anywhere.